# How to verify POST file transfer with python requests library?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using the python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) library's Session feature to request dynamically generated images from a remote server and write them to a file. The remote server is often unreliable and will respond with an html document, or pieces of the image. What is the best way to verify that the content is indeed the right format (not html), and has completely loaded? (my formats are png and csv) An example of my code is as follows:

```
import requests
ses = requests.Session()
data = ses.get("http://url")
localDest = os.path.join("local/file/path")
with open(localDest,'wb') as f:
   for chunk in data.iter_content()
      f.write(chunk)
```

How would I modify this code to check that it is the right format, and is a complete file?

Comment: Do you have control over the remote server? Instead of serving an image, if the server is serving an html page, I'm guessing that's an error  page, in which case it should be accompanied with a non-200 HTTP status code.

Comment: I have no control over the remote server. So adding the status code check would be the first thing, but what about incomplete files?

Comment: How are incomplete files manifested? Is a certain `Content-Length` promised?

Comment: right format you can use mime-types, for the competence of the file you can try to compare md5 checksums ( if remote server provide some )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. If the server gave correct information in the headers about the content, check that for an invalid content type or an invalid content length.
2. If the server is lying about the content type or sets a content length to the size of the incomplete image, validate the content afterwards.

The following does *both*:

```
import imghdr
import os
import os.path
import requests
import shutil

ses = requests.Session()
r = ses.get("http://url", stream=True)
localDest = os.path.join("local/file/path")

if r.status_code == 200:
    ctype = r.headers.get('content-type', '')
    if ctype.partition('/')[0].lower() != 'image':
        raise ValueError('Not served an image')

    clength = r.headers.get('content-length')
    clength = clength and int(clength)

    with open(localDest, 'wb') as f:
        r.raw.decode_content = True
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)        

    if clength and os.path.getsize(localDest) != clength:
        os.remove(localDest)
        raise ValueError('Served incomplete response')

    image_type = imghdr.test(localDest)
    if image_type is None:
        os.remove(localDest)
        raise ValueError('Not served an image')
```

You can also install [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/) and validate the image further with that.

Comment: this worked great with the exception that I needed to change content_type to content-type and content_length to content-length